# How can I get number of bytes in com port, using boost::asio::serial_port

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost to work with a virtual com port. There is a function `read_some()`, which requires the size of the data being received. Now I'm using a fixed buffer with a length of 1024, but in general this does not seem like a good solution. I need to know how many bytes I have in the port before reading from it.

Do you know have any ideas about receiving this value? Maybe without using boost, but better with.

Comment: You can't, boost doesn't expose that implementation detail.  It is never required, serial ports sit at the very bottom of the OSI model and acts as byte streams.  So the number of bytes you get is entirely unpredictable.  Since they are slow, you usually get only a handful at most.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662782/cserial-communicatio-using-the-windows-h-how-can-i-find-out-before-hand

Comment: I think it's possible today with latest Asio library